# Fixing broken external HDD partition

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, ntfs

Basically I used Quick Format on a HDD (300GB ish) and I was changing it from NTFS to FAT32 I believe it was a while back so I cant remember much but it basically just stopped working. Now it wont even show up on my PC.

I had a look at this TestDisk app and its showing my disk but I have no idea where to go from here.

EDIT: Seems like im using this analyze function to check for partitions as none could be found.

Answer (score 0):

**Found a fix! Simply deleted the MRB and Partition Table and made new MRB and Table!**

I made a...

## HUGE

documentation on fixing HDD's including the method I used to fix my issue.

[Click here](https://superuser.com/questions/972303/recover-broken-partition-hdd) to check it out there's a few methods there that could help you :)